# Creating XSD file

Tags: xml, xsd

i have a xml file a now i need creating XSD.
the xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <ErrorMessageGroup>
    <group name="Common" description="Obecné chyby" />
    <group name="Authorize" description="Chyby autorizace" />
  </ErrorMessageGroup>
  <message errorMessageGroup="Common" code="" value="" />
  <message errorMessageGroup="Authorize" code="" value="" />
</resources>
```

Visual studio generate me xsd file and I need create restriction for attribute errorMessageGroup in message element that only valid values will be values from name attribute of group element...

how can i do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xsd for your xml and have a look at the restriction for errorMessage group

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="resources">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ErrorMessageGroup"/>
                    <xs:element ref="message" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="message">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="value" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="errorMessageGroup" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Authorize"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Common"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="code" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="group">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Authorize"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Common"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="description" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Chyby autorizace"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Obecné chyby"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ErrorMessageGroup">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="group" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```